# Order Categories by a custom order in wp_dropdown_categories

Tags: wordpress, sql-order-by

I use the `wp_dropdown_categories( $args )` function to show/select certain categories. The default-setting shows the category titles in the drop-down-menu-list alphabetically `('orderby' => 'name')`.

Because I my site has an event list, I have 7 categories, one each day i.e. "Monday", "Tuesday", .... "Sunday".

Because of `'orderby' => 'name'` these categories are ordered alphabetically:
"*Dienstag*" (Tuesday), "*Donnerstag*" (Thursday) etc.

I want to order/show them in the right sequence for days of the week, i.e. Beginning with "*Montag*" (Monday) and ending with "*Sonntag*"(Sunday).

How can I specify a custom order for this?

Comment: Do you need this sort order only in a situation where you display those day name options only, or do you need this when showing _all_ options - and have only these few sorted alphabetically, and the rest by a different criterion? Please give specific examples as to what you need and where.

Comment: i need this only to show it finer in the drop-down menu. it begins in the top of the opened drop-down-menu-list  with "D" for Dienstag (tuesday) than Donnerstag (thursday)....etc. it would be finer when it  would begin with Montag (monday) than Dienstag (tuesday) etc.

Comment: If you're willing to sacrifice all "dynamism" and are happy with a static solution that will only work for your site, and as long as you don't modify anything about these existing terms, you could simply go with orderby=include, and list the term ids in the `include` array/string in the right order. If you need it to be more flexible than that, you could use a plugin like https://wordpress.org/plugins/taxonomy-terms-order/ that will allow you to sort your terms via drag&drop in the backend, and then lets you order them in queries using orderby=term_order.

Comment: via include and list the (only) 7 categories individual by id...very fine!  thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

you can change 'orderby'=> 'ID','order'=> 'ASC' in wp_dropdown_categories( $args )

[https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_dropdown_categories/](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_dropdown_categories)

Comment: this would be a possibility. But my categories of the 7 weekdays dont have the IDs in the right sequence...monday-category-id is higher than tuesday-category. Or sunday-catgegory-id has an id which is smaller than the saturday-category-id. Because of this an order by ID makes no sense. It would be possible, if i could give them an own ID. But i think that is not easy to do.

Comment: you can try this plugin https://wordpress.org/plugins/taxonomy-terms-order/